# Available video encoders on Lenovo L580

Tags: video, lenovo-laptop, encoding

I have a Lenovo ThinkPad L580 and want to transcode many DVD rips using a tool called [other_video_transcoding](https://github.com/donmelton/other_video_transcoding/) by Don Melton. This tool allows many different video encoders, and now I am struggling how to figure out which one to use. In the end i want to be able to choose which encoder I should use, but in the first place I need to find out which encoders are available. How do I do that? I am firmly used to cmd, but can also use powershell or gitbash if necessary.

Comment: The whole point of that tool is that it is automated ...

Comment: Still there are people who recommend different options for different use cases, and I would like to know which of these are of interest for me and which aren’t. I would like to post a question on GitHub about which options to use, but for that I need to know what I actually can use